# How to compute this loop integral?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, yang-mills

I have a gauge boson that splits into two scalars and the loop is closed by a gauge boson as shown in the picture. The incoming boson has $\mu$ index while the boson that runs in the loop has momentum $p$.

[image]

What is the integral for this boson? Note that it is non-Abelian so in each vertex we have to include a generator $t^a$. I know that the integral will be like
$$ \int \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4} g^3 t^bt^at^b \frac{?}{(p+k')^2 (p+k)^2p^2} $$
Right? But what is the numerator and how we solve this integral? I know what the group generators give me, I don't know **the form of the numerator and most probably how to integrate it**.

P.S. The momentum $p$ of the internal boson points upwards.
P.S. 2 Also the internal line are scalars not fermions. I have only scalars and gauge bosons.
P.S.3 After searching around I think that my question can be limited on what is the vertex of the gauge boson-scalar intersection? this is what will go in the numerator. We see 3 vertices in the diagram, thus we need three terms!

Comment: No I won't. There are no fermions involved.

Comment: No problem. But any help welcome.

Comment: What is the boson-scalar vertex? I don't recall ever seeing it before.

Comment: You can have it e.g. in supersymmetry.

Comment: So you have a Lagrangian? Can't you use the standard Feynman procedure? (I don't know how to do this, it's just how I would try to approach it.)

Comment: Yes, but you know as you see its pretty standard. You have to put the propagators correctly inside the integral. The thing is I am not sure on what happens with the currents running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your theory is anything like scalar-QCD then the gauge field couples to the scalar current through a "derivative" interaction 
$$A^\mu J_\mu \supset A^\mu \; \left( \phi^\ast \partial_\mu \phi - \phi \partial_\mu \phi^\ast  \right)$$

This would mean that each of the gauge-boson scalar vertices will have a factor of the scalar momentum, in the numerator. For eg: look at this: http://physics.indiana.edu/~sg/p622/qft-II_S61-63.pdf (particularly slides 4 and 20).

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes, I know there must be scalar currents running inside. I am not sure though how to write them in the numerator of my integral where I put ?. I could not find the specific diagram in the notes you say to me.

Comment: Ah, those slides start with the Feynman rules for scalar+gauge theory but then switch to QED. The way to write the numerators is to start at a particular vertex or propagator, and then go around the loop. Since this diagram has only bosons, the order in which you multiply contributions from the vertices and propagators will not matter. If you had QED, for example, the $\gamma$-matrices on the fermion-fermion-photon vertices would not commute and you would have to keep careful track of the ordering.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I figure this out so I wrote down the vertices. Now, there is an ambiguity. Should this diagram be zero? Is there any chance it is zero? The corresponding diagram of QCD where instead of scalars you have fermions does not vanish, but my calculation shows that this one does.